# Is it possible to include selectInput element in navlistPanel in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

In my current application I am using a `navlistPanel` similar to the one below and I was wondering whether it would be possible to add a `selectInput` UI element to the navlist?

I have tried this in my `ui.R` but it doesn't work:

```
fluidPage(

 titlePanel("Application Title"),

 navlistPanel(
   "Header",
   tabPanel("First"),
   tabPanel("Second"),
   tabPanel("Third")
   # selectInput(inputId, label, choices, selected = NULL) <- I've tried this but it doesn't work
 )
)
```

Any solutions/workarounds are welcome.

I was wondering whether using `sidebarLayout` + `sidebarPanel` would work where the `sidebarPanel` imitates the behaviour of a `navlistPanel` but wasn't able to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are okay with using `shinydashboard`, it is fairly simple.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

rm(list=ls)

######/ UI Side/######

header <- dashboardHeader(title = "Test")
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("First Tab",tabName = "FTab", icon = icon("globe")),
    menuItem("Second Tab",tabName = "STab", icon = icon("star"))
  ),
  selectInput("navSel", "Selection:", c("b","c"))
)
body <- dashboardBody()

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)


######/ SERVER Side/######

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi Kevin. Thanks for your answer, on this occasion I can't rewrite the app to use shinydashboard but it's good to know that this feature is available within the shinydashboard package. Cheers.

Comment: OK, so after much deliberation I decided to move over to shinydashboard, so I am going to accept your answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

A clean solution will be difficult, but how about something like this:

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Application Title"),

    navlistPanel("Header", id = "navOut",
                 tabPanel("First", "First"),
                 tabPanel(selectInput("navSel", "Selection:", c("b", "c")), textOutput("txt"))
    )
  ),
  server <- shinyServer(function(input, output){
    output$txt <- renderText(input$navSel)
  })  
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I think this is probably the easiest solution if you are controlling outputs within a give tabPanel. Unfortunately, the way the app is designed is that the selctInput controls outputs in two different tabPanels..not to worry though it can be solved by adding an additional control layer..thanks for your help!